# Characters on lattices and isogenies of Abelian varieties

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, reference-request, abelian-varieties

Let $V:=\mathbb{C}^g$ and $\Lambda \subset V$ be a lattice, i.e. a discrete subgroup of rank $2g$. Then $A:=V/ \Lambda$ is a complex torus of dimension $g$. We moreover assume that $A$ is algebraic, hence an Abelian variety.

Let $\mathcal{L} \in \textrm{Pic}^0(A)$ be a line bundle of finite order $n$. By the classical Appell-Humbert theorem, it corresponds to a character $$\chi \colon \Lambda \longrightarrow \mathbb{C}^*$$ with values in the subgroup $\mu_n$ of n-th roots of unity.

On the other hand, we can associate to $\mathcal{L}$, and hence to $\chi$, a degree $n$ isogeny $$f_\chi \colon A_{\chi} \longrightarrow A.$$
This in turns determines a sublattice $\Lambda_\chi \subset \Lambda$ such that $A_\chi = V/\Lambda_\chi$ and $[\Lambda\, : \, \Lambda_\chi]=n.$

> **Question.** How can we explicitly write down a basis of $\Lambda_{\chi}$ in terms of a basis of $\Lambda$ and the character $\chi$?

I can guess the answer in some easy cases, but I would prefer a general statement and, possibly, a precise reference. I am rather sure that this is well-known to the experts, so I'm writing here in order to get a pointer to some relevant statement in the huge literature of the field.

Comment: $\Lambda_{\chi } $ is just the kernel of $\chi $. What else do you want?

Comment: Ok, I see. Taking $\Lambda_{\chi}= \ker \chi$ we obtain $$f_{\chi}^* \mathcal{L} = \mathcal{O}_{A_{\chi}},$$ since the pullback via $f_{\chi}$ is given by the restriction of the character to $\Lambda_{\chi}$.  I was looking for a proof which was more in the spirit of Appell-Humbert's, or for a reference. But I'm happy with this argument, too. Thanks.